# System.Drawing.Color equality operator doesn't treat 0xffffffff as Color.White

Tags: .net, colors, system.drawing, system.drawing.color

Why does this evaluate to `false`?

```
Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255) == Color.White
```

**Update** It's by design.

Here's a copy from the decompiled `Equals` function in the `Color` structure:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    //probably failure to convert from C++ source,
    //the following line should be invalid in C#, nevermind
    if (obj is Color)
    {
        Color color = (Color) obj;
        if (((this.value == color.value) &&
            (this.state == color.state)) &&
             (this.knownColor == color.knownColor))
        {
            return ((this.name == color.name) || 
                   (((this.name != null) && (color.name != null)) && 
                   this.name.Equals(this.name)));
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My question is why on earth would MSFT have me comparing to white the ugly way?!?!?

```
static bool AreEqual(Color a, Color b)
{
  if (!a.Equals(b))
  {
    return
      a.A == b.A &&
      a.R == b.R &&
      a.G == b.G &&
      a.B == b.B;    
  }
  return true;
}
```

Also, another thing I don't get why the 1-arg overload of the `FromArgb` function in `Color` takes an `int`, it should be able to take a `uint` (`0xffffffff`)

Comment: did you see if `Color.White` has an `alpha value`?

Comment: Microsoft decided to allow .net software to be written in languages without unsigned types; toward that end, they have decreed that all framework features should be usable without needing such types.  I think they should have added a few more exceptions (e.g. overloads of `Interlocked` methods for such types--such overloads wouldn't be usable in languages without such types, but they wouldn't be needed either).  Even though ARGB parameter should logically be an unsigned type, using an unsigned parameter there would have prevented single-parameter color construction in languages without uint32.

Comment: That having been said, I think there should have been a `FromRGB` which would use the bottom 24 bits of an Int32, and FromAlphaRGB which would take an alpha value in one Int32 and RGB in the bottom 24 bits of another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just [how colors in .NET work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.equals%28v=VS.71%29.aspx):

> This structure only does comparisons with other Color structures. To
>   compare colors based solely on their ARGB values, you should do the
>   following:
>
> if ( color1.ToArgb() == color2.ToArgb()) ...
>
> **This is because the .Equals and == operators determine equivalency
>   using more than just the ARGB value of the colors**. For example,
>   Color.Black and Color.FromArgb(0,0,0) are not considered equal since
>   Color.Black is a named color and Color.FromArgb(0,0,0) is not.

**Edit**: additional answers.

> My question is why on earth would MSFT have me comparing to white the ugly way?!?!?

If you're comparing colors in such a way that you want to know whether they're exactly the same color down to the values of the ARGB components, then you *should* be comparing them in the "ugly" way. If you're comparing the colors in the same way that most .NET programmers use the `Color` structure, then you only want to know if some color is `White` or `Red` or `Chartreuse`, and the "pretty" way (using Equals and ==) is simple, easy to use, and very readable.

Also, the "ugly" way isn't the method you posted, it's this:

```
if (color1.ToArgb() == color2.ToArgb()) ...
```

which isn't really that ugly.

> Also, another thing I don't get why the 1-arg constructor of Color takes an int, it should be able to take a uint (0xffffffff)

I would say it should *not* be able to take a `uint`, thanks to the inevitable confusion and color errors that would cause. It's easy to write a method to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Color is a structure and it contains more than the four byte values.
Try this:

```
Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255).ToArgb() == Color.White.ToArgb()
```

Answer (score 1):

The Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255) is not a named color, so its Name property will be ffffff and for the named color, Color.White the Name will be White. SO your comparison will not work

You can either use

```
Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255).ToArgb() == Color.White.ToArgb()
```

or

```
(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255).R == Color.White.R && Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255).G == Color.White.G && Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255).B == Color.White.B && Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255).A == Color.White.A)
```

Comment: I've added another issue to my question, see last line.

Answer (score 0):

If i have to use HTML color (which I prefer), i use this:
TextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF")

Comment: If you're determined to use the code you posted, remove one of the 255's:
TextBox.BackColor= System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)
Do you have to specify the alpha?  The intellisense says (paraphrase) "Although it accepts 32-bit value, each parameter value is limited to 8bits). So maybe it's not 255 as you're expecting it to be when you compare it.

Answer (score 0):

The name is different, see these results in the Immediate window:

```
?Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255)
"{Name=ffffffff, ARGB=(255, 255, 255, 255)}"
    A: 255
    B: 255
    G: 255
    IsEmpty: false
    IsKnownColor: false
    IsNamedColor: false
    IsSystemColor: false
    Name: "ffffffff"
    R: 255

?Color.White
"{Name=White, ARGB=(255, 255, 255, 255)}"
    A: 255
    B: 255
    G: 255
    IsEmpty: false
    IsKnownColor: true
    IsNamedColor: true
    IsSystemColor: false
    Name: "White"
    R: 255
```

Answer (score 0):

I just spent 30 minutes researching this cause you got me all curious about it too, but when i got back, looks like others posted exactly what i found.
You're comparing two different things.  You have to put them on the same level so you can then compare them, be it using one of the system.drawing properties or one of the other posters suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class ExtendsUInt32
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a System.UInt32 to a System.Drawing.Color.
        /// Ex: var orangyColor = (0xFFDDAA22).ToColor(); //some kind of orange
        /// <remarks>
        /// Easier than writing var orangyColor = Color.FromArgb(unchecked((int)0xFFDDAA22))),
        /// or var orangyColor = Color.FromArgb(255,230,200,50);
        /// </remarks>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="color">A uint containing bytes A,R,G,B in high-to-low order (whatever this stores as on your platform's endianness).</param>
        /// <returns>A freshly picked System.Drawing.Color.</returns>
        public static Color ToColor(this UInt32 color)
        {
            var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(color);
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) { bytes = bytes.Reverse().ToArray(); }
            return Color.FromArgb(bytes[0],bytes[1],bytes[2],bytes[3]);
        }
    }
```